# How do I shop for an efficient low-current buck-boost converter?

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter

I'm working on a low-power battery-powered application running at 3.3V; it needs a DC-DC converter to efficiently draw power from a range of possible battery combinations connected by the end user.

In short, here are my top priorities:

- wide supply range (around 2-16 V)
- ability to output at least 50 mA
- high`efficiency at 10 mA
- price under $10

I'm currently achieving those top priorities using the [LT3129-1](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/31291fb.pdf), and am now trying to achieve some secondary priorities:

- low parts count (ideally monolithic)
- low ripple in output signal
- won't be damaged by reverse voltage or moderate overvoltage on supply

However, I'm having trouble searching for better options because it seems like nearly everything I see is inefficient at such low currents, and there are too many options among DC-DC converters (e.g. at Digikey) to find the needles in the haystack.

Can anyone recommend either a search term for my needs, or a specific product? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the fixation over efficiencies at low output currents. They are all going to be the same.

Comment: At such low currents, you may want to consider a linear regulator. They actually can be more efficient than switching regulators at sufficiently low currents. You won't be able to get the bottom part of your range, though, and efficiency depends on input voltage.

Comment: I don't understand the question about efficiency at low output current--I gain almost 20% battery life at 95% efficiency vs 80% efficiency. That's a very big deal in my intended uses. I'm not an expert on DC-DC converters and you may know something I don't--why would they all "be the same"?

Comment: I've ruled out linear regulators because if a user supplied, for example, 9V, it would only run at 37% efficiency, giving well under half the potential battery life. Plus, if they use 3 D cells in series, they'd lose significant battery life corresponding to the part of the discharge curve with Vbatt < 1.1V. I know that at least one highly efficient low-current switching regulator exists (the LT3129-1) and am trying to find others.

Comment: Please link the device that gives 95% efficiency at 10 mA and can still work just as efficiently (or better) when delivering 50 mA to the load.

Comment: Here's the LT3129-1 referred to in the post: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/31291fb.pdf  Not quite 95%, but 90% at both 10 mA and 50 mA.

Comment: Basically "worry the selection tables to death". You probably need synchronous rectification, hiccup mode at low load, probably external FETS (so you can use super low Rdson etc ), high but not too high operating frequency, low loss inductor,  .... . . The LTC3129 is useful but eg it has a poor RDson switch (0.5 to 1 ohm+). Look at smps driver ICs and external FETS.

Answer (score 1):

A regulated charge pump can be more efficient at low currents; check out the LTC3246:
https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc3246.html

This type replaces the switching inductance with capacitance, which can make the overall circuit smaller and cheaper as well.  Ripple will probably vary by input voltage and input stability; at lower input voltages, it just functions as an LDO.

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation! I hadn't heard of regulated charge pumps before. Is the distinct "sawtooth" shape to the efficiency curve typical of all similar products? The fact that its efficiency varies so much depending on Vin means it might not work for my application.

Comment: Yes, this is typical.  A basic charge pump is just a voltage multiplier (or divider, in this case), so the LDO absorbs more power as you move away from even multiples.  For example, 7V is linearly regulated down to 6.6V then switched down to 3.3V; 9V undergoes the same process, but more is absorbed in the linear stage.  The jumps in efficiency happen as the switching ratio goes from _2:1_  -->  _1:1_  -->  _1:2_.

Answer (score 1):

At these currents, the Rdson of the '3129 switches is fine. You don't want really low Rdson FETs at these power levels or you'll lose too much energy due to gate charge.